# Nlohmann json get with type deduction

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

With [`nlohmann::json`](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/) an object can be parsed using a couple different expressions:

1. `type x = json;`
2. `type x; x = json.get<type>();`

However, `type x; x = json;` doesn't work, because that would require adding a new assignment operator for `type`.

I find myself needing to use expression (2) more often then expression (1). This can get quite annoying, especially if `type` is something complicated.
In a few cases, I defined

```
template <typename U>
void convert(const json& j, U& x) { x = j.get<U>(); }
```

But it would be nice if `get` had an overload taking a reference as an argument, so that the following would be possible.

```
type x;
json.get(x);
```

Is there already a function that does that, that just has a different name? I couldn't find one in the documentation.

**Edit**: I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1227) on GitHub.

**Edit 2**: An alternative to the `get` function, `T& get_to(T&)`, will be included in release 3.3.0.

Comment: "But it would be nice if get had an overload taking a reference as an argument" - why do you not get in touch with the library author then and suggest that. Maybe even contribute a patch. ?

Answer (score 2):

> However, `type x; x = json;` doesn't work

It actually does work. The `basic_json` type [has a templated conversion operator](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/d713727f2277f2eb919a2dbbfdd534f8988aa493/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp#L13945) which just calls `get<T>()` for you. The following code [compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/bamKvC):

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using nlohmann::json;

namespace ns {
    struct MyType {
        int i;
    };

    void to_json(json& j, MyType m) {
        j = json{{"i", m.i}};
    }

    void from_json(json const& j, MyType& m) {
        m.i = j.at("i");
    }
}

int main() {
    json j{{"i", 42}};
    ns::MyType type;
    type = j;
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to always work. You commented on another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50881469/2640636) I asked a couple months ago.

Comment: @SU3 When it doesn't work, it's because it can't determine which `ValueType` to deduce for the templated conversion operator. It could convert to multiple different types, so it's ambiguous.

Comment: @SU3 It worked fine on Godbolt but not on your machine because you need to update nlohmann json. Select an older version of nlohmann json and you can see the same error (you removed that part of your comment, just want to be clear why it happened).

Comment: I removed that part because I noticed that there were still warnings.

Comment: @SU3 That is... peculiar. Indeed there is apparently a warning (but it looks a lot like an error), but it's just giving us the stack trace instead of any diagnostic. That's probably a GCC bug (would want to verify it offline to be sure). Clang rejects it with a more reasonable error message (https://godbolt.org/z/AGTc8T)

Comment: `GCC 7.2.0` gives an error with `-std=c++14` (that's what I normally use for compatibility reasons with other libraries) and the same warnings as Godbolt with `-std=c++17`.